# Proper patterns to manage multiple struct types with the same interface in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm implementing Async TCP- and TLS-stream with Rust and wanting the same code support both cases. Currently, I ended up defining all streams as

```
enum Stream {
    TCP(Async::<TcpStream>),
    TLS(TlsStream<Async::<TcpStream>>)
}
```

but that would mean that I need to use match to dig stream out when I use it. I don't think this is pro-way to do it.

I tried to define the used stream through trait (interface) with

```
tx_stream: Arc<dyn AsyncWriteExt + Send + 'static>
```

but that complains of not knowing the sizes of the types. Also, the Stream classes has quite a few traits and I don't think I should be tagging them all into the implementation.

Lastly, I was thinking of using generics but that I guess would double the code size as there would be two different structs and the related code would need to be generated accordingly.

What would be the "pro"-way to accomplish something like this? In C++, interface class and two different object behind factory pattern would do the trick. I'm sure there is some clever way to do this with Rust but haven't really found anything sensible so far.

Comment: I don't understand. Although you have a `TcpStream` in both cases, surely they are used very differently. Having a common interface to the underlying stream is not very helpful, even in C++ you would need two separate adaptor classes... same amount of code compared to what you probable have now?

Comment: Go for generics. `Stream<T>` with only two variants of `T` is the least overhead and you won't even notice it in a size of a binary, unless you go embedded. Generics would be a problem if it would be `Stream<A, B, C, D>` with a hundred of combinations. In the end, there many more generics in the standard library in both Rust and C++ and no one really complains when using many `Vec<T>` or `std::vector<T>` implementations

Comment: @rodrigo You are right that if I were to use existing classes for TCP/IP and TLS stream implementations, I would need to create adapter classes even in C++ to make them use the same interface. I guess I could do the same with Rust to have my own trait and then create adapter structs but potentially hoped to reuse the existing traits as most of them are the same between the streams.

Comment: @AlexLarionov Based on the current discussions in Reddit and other things I found, it seems that generics is the most Rustian way to go forward. Also, in the most cases the save application won't use both flavors so there wouldn't even be the binary size hit if done right as the "unused" type is optimized out from the binary.